# Что делает данный код filter_input?

Tags: php, веб-программирование

Не могу понять, что данный код делает? Дампил, но ничего не заметил

```
$data = [];
foreach ($_POST as $key => $val {
   $data[$key] = filter_input(INPUT_POST, $key, FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS);
}
var_dump($data);
```

То же самое и такое для $_GET

Расскажите пожалуйста по подробнее и с примерами, а на официальном сайте пхп вообще шляпа какая-та

Answer (score 0):

у вас ошибка в примере, нужно писать $val вместо $key в filter_input. Вы работаете со значением,  а не ключом.
В конкретном примере с типом фильтра FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS, это если в полученных данных есть символы '"<>&, то эти символы будут закодированы, т.е. в var_dump вы увидите вместо них типа `&amp;`

Comment: ааа, понял. А для чего это делается?

Comment: фильтрация данных нужна, для того чтобы в бд писались "чистые данные", email должен быть email, строка - строкой, число - числом. Чтобы иньекцию не сделали, через спецсимволы.

Comment: Так для этого есть mysqli_real_escape_string() зачем тогда фильтр?